Using a low voltage to drive a switch carrying high voltage
I need to create a switch that will close the gap between a source and drain that are 44V and 40V, respectively. However, I would like to drive that switch with only a 2V signal. What is the best way to go about this?

What other supply voltages are available in the circuit? What range of voltage and current do these 44 and 40V nodes possess? (If you don't know, showing schematics of all surrounding circuitry would be the easiest way to show.)

@TimWilliams probably meant to say respectively

Provide lots more about the load being switched and the 2 V source. You write almost nothing of use so far. Provide as much information as you can. Do not hold back anything. Both what you know and the known unknowns. Otherwise don't expect a useful answer.

Source and drain are the names of two pins on a MOSFET. Are you looking for a device to short the pins of a transistor?

@TimWilliams  I removed the first sentence from your otherwise useful comment. I assume that you realised that it was a typo. Pointing this out or editing (as Toolic did) are both OK. [[New contributors can be discouraged by minor adverse input. Some think this is a good idea. Ideally allowing people to 'find their feet' is desirable. ]]

@RussellMcMahon I honestly didn't; maybe I'm still adjusting to the abundance of autocorrect (mobile text, LLM?) these days, but since it could also be parsed as a phatic expression ("respectfully, I need to..") I wondered if showing an alternative (potentially unintended) parsing of that sentence could encourage clarity.

@TimWilliams  Thanks for the response. Sorry to be excessively 'protective'. Mayhaps I'm too used to Facebook where such corrections seem to be the order of the day :-(. The rest of your comment was entirely reasonable. (You knew that :-) ).

You are looking for a MOSFET + high side gate driver chip with an input that can be driven by a 2V input signal or a high side load switch with the same. There are some current-controlled devices out there that may be easier to use with a low input voltage. If large currents flow between the two nodes, then a discrete pass element may be the only feasible solution.
